# ng-click inside ui-gmap-windows not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

**ng-click inside ui-gmap-windows not working...**
Here is codepen link [http://codepen.io/aoakeson/pen/ZYLJeyhttp://codepen.io/aoakeson/pen/ZYLJey](http://codepen.io/aoakeson/pen/ZYLJey)

Any suggestion as how this issue is to be solved....

Here is html code:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' draggable="true">
             <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" click="'onClick'">

                 <ui-gmap-windows show="show" ng-cloak>
                     <div class="lp_tuxtla" >
        <div >
            <a ng-click="nextpage()">click here</a>
            <h3 ng-non-bindable >{{title}}</h3>
            <h4 ng-non-bindable>{{loc}}</h4>
        </div>
        <span class="right_arw"></span>
        <span class="down_arw"></span>
    </div>

          <!--  <div ng-non-bindable >{{title}}</div>-->
        </ui-gmap-windows>

    </ui-gmap-markers>
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Here javascript code:

```
$scope.map = {center: {latitude: 40.1451, longitude: -99.6680 }, zoom: 4, bounds: {}};
    $scope.options = {scrollwheel: false};
    var createRandomMarker = function (i, bounds, idKey) {
        var lat_min = bounds.southwest.latitude,
            lat_range = bounds.northeast.latitude - lat_min,
            lng_min = bounds.southwest.longitude,
            lng_range = bounds.northeast.longitude - lng_min;

        if (idKey == null) {
            idKey = "id";
        }

        var latitude = lat_min + (Math.random() * lat_range);
        var longitude = lng_min + (Math.random() * lng_range);
        var ret = {
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude,
            title: 'm' + i,
            show: false
        };
        ret.onClick = function() {
            console.log("Clicked!");
            ret.show = !ret.show;
        };
        ret[idKey] = i;
        return ret;
    };
    $scope.randomMarkers = [];
    // Get the bounds from the map once it's loaded
    $scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.map.bounds; }, function(nv, ov) {
        // Only need to regenerate once
        if (!ov.southwest && nv.southwest) {
            var markers = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                markers.push(createRandomMarker(i, $scope.map.bounds))
            }
            $scope.randomMarkers = markers;
        }
    }, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Somehow, its not able to reach the 'windowClicked' method in the hierarchy.

Create the method on rootScope and use it in the tempalte.

**In Controller**

```
$scope.$root.windowClicked = function () {alert('here')}
```

**In Markup**

```
<a ng-click="$root.windowClicked()">test</a>
```

Here is the updated pen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEKjjb

Answer (score 3):

### First way

You can use your `$scope` declared variables in `ng-click` using `$parent`:

```
<button ng-click="$parent.nextPage()">next</button>
```

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XrEhq9QWoUu9F5mZjW2X?p=preview).

### Second way

You can assign a controller to the div containing the window.

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <button ng-click="nextPage()">next</button>
</div>
```

Here is another [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rlscusYzQsdVu6nlOCM0?p=preview)

### Credits

People in [Github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/356)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is the same issue that has been discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/356).
Apparently it occurs since `nextpage` event declared in controller scope is not accessible from the `ui-gmap-windows` child scope.

The following solution worked for me:

First we need to introduce an additional controller:

```
appMaps.controller('infoWindowCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showInfo = function() {
        console.log('Button clicked!');
    }
});
```

and then specify the following layout:

```
<ui-gmap-windows show="show">
      <div ng-controller="infoWindowCtrl">
          <span ng-non-bindable>{{title}}</span>
          <button ng-click="showInfo()">Show info</button>
       </div>
</ui-gmap-windows>
```

**Working example**

```js
var appMaps = angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
appMaps.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,uiGmapIsReady) {
    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 40.1451, longitude: -99.6680 }, zoom: 4, bounds: {} };
    $scope.options = { scrollwheel: false };

    var getRandomLat = function() {
        return Math.random() * (90.0 + 90.0) - 90.0;
    };
    var getRandomLng = function () {
        return Math.random() * (180.0 + 180.0) - 180.0;
    };

    var createRandomMarker = function(i) {
        var ret = {
            latitude: getRandomLat(),
            longitude: getRandomLng(),
            title: 'm' + i,
            show: false,
            id: i
        };
        return ret;
    };
    $scope.onClick = function(marker, eventName, model) {
        logInfo("Marker clicked!");
        model.show = !model.show;
    };
    $scope.markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        $scope.markers.push(createRandomMarker(i));
    }

});

appMaps.controller('infoWindowCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showInfo = function() {
        logInfo('Button clicked!');
    }
});


function logInfo(message){
   console.log(message);
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += message;
}
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
    position: relative;
}

.angular-google-map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appMaps" id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
            <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" click="onClick">
                <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
                    <div ng-controller="infoWindowCtrl">
                        <span ng-non-bindable>{{title}}</span>
                        <button ng-click="showInfo()">Show info</button>
                    </div>
                </ui-gmap-windows>
            </ui-gmap-markers>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jO2nkIk1Nk2lu2wmRBlv?p=preview)